# Gradle Kotlin Script, trying to assign classpatch via builtin variable

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Why this:

```
val runVersionSplicer by tasks.registering(type = JavaExec::class) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath // error
    main = "com.concurnas.build.VersionSplicer"
}
```

returns:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
>   public val NamedDomainObjectContainer.runtimeClasspath: NamedDomainObjectProvider defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

While this works fine instead?

```
val runVersionSplicer by tasks.registering(type = JavaExec::class) {
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.concurnas.build.VersionSplicer"
}
```

I know that `sourceSets.main` is so defined:

```
val org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetContainer.`main`: NamedDomainObjectProvider<org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet>
    get() = named<org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet>("main")
```

However isn't supposed to replace the `sourceSets["main"]` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one of them is a provider and the other is the object.

- `sourceSets.main` uses `NamedDomainObjectCollection.named` under the hood as you found out. If you look at the javadoc for `named`, you see that it returns the following:

  > A Provider that will return the object when queried. The object may be created and configured at this point, if not already
- `sourceSets["main"]` returns the source set directly, because it uses `NamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName` instead, whi:

  > The object with the given name. Never returns null.

So these two are equivalent:

```
sourceSets.main.get()
sourceSets["main"]
```

In Groovy the following are equivalent:

```
sourceSets.main
sourceSets["main"]
sourceSets.getAt("main")
```

Which are all different syntax of the `getAt` method implemented by the `NamedDomainObjectCollection` class. This is why you don't see a lot of `get()` in Groovy scripts but you see a lot more in Kotlin DSL scripts.